# Running LLVM for C++ is not working on GraalVM docker container - oracle/graalvm-ce:19.1.1

Tags: graalvm

I tried to execute simple cpp code from graalvm documents https://www.graalvm.org/docs/getting-started/#running-llvm-interpreter , it is giving below error.

```
bash-4.2# lli --version
LLVM (GraalVM CE Native 19.1.1)
bash-4.2# clang++ -c -O1 -emit-llvm -stdlib=libc++ hello1.cpp
bash-4.2# lli hello1.bc
Global variable _ZNSt3__15ctypeIcE2idE is declared but not defined.
        at <llvm> null(Unknown)
```

Below is the code i used from graalvm website.

```
bash-4.2# cat hello1.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, C++ World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Docker image details:-

GRAALVM_PKG=https://github.com/oracle/graal/releases/download/vm-19.1.1/graalvm-ce-linux-amd64-19.1.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `clang++` from the LLVM_TOOLCHAIN installable, not the system clang.

```
$ gu install llvm-toolchain
$ export LLVM_TOOLCHAIN=$(lli --print-toolchain-path)
$ $LLVM_TOOLCHAIN/clang++ hello1.cpp -o hello1
$ lli hello1
Hello, C++ World!
```

I think the reason is that by default the symbols are mangled or something like that.